# Dropwizard 0.8.1 File Upload

Tags: java, jersey-2.0, dropwizard

I have been trying to upload file to dropwizard 0.8.1 but unable to do so. Every time I hit upload call resource method doesn't get invoked.
Seems like I have had a version mismatch issue. Below is my configuration/version file.

```html
buildscript {
  repositories {
    mavenCentral()
  }

  dependencies {
    // this plugin
    classpath 'org.jsonschema2pojo:jsonschema2pojo-gradle-plugin:0.4.14'
    // add additional dependencies here if you wish to reference instead of generate them (see example directory)
  }
}

plugins {
    id 'eclipse'
    id 'application'
    id 'com.github.johnrengelman.shadow' version '1.2.1'
    id "org.flywaydb.flyway" version "3.2.1"
}

if (System.getProperty("jsonschema2pojo")) {
    apply plugin: 'jsonschema2pojo'
} 
apply plugin: 'java'



version = '0.1'

configurations {
    all*.exclude group: 'com.sun.jersey', module: 'jersey-core'
    all*.exclude group: 'org.slf4j', module: 'slf4j-simple'
}

project.ext {
    dropwizardVersion = '0.8.1'
    dropwizardSwaggerVersion = '0.7.0'
    dropwizardConfig = './src/main/resources/qlue-config.yml'
    dropwizardMetrics = '3.1.0'
    postgresVersion = '9.4-1201-jdbc41'
    apacheCommonsBeanUtilsVersion = '1.9.2'
    lombokVersion = '1.16.6'
    junitVersion = '4.12'
    oauthVersion = '1.0.0'
    postgresEmbedded = '1.5-SNAPSHOT'
    freemakerVersion = '2.3.23'
    websocketBundle = '1.0.0'
    reactorVersion = '2.0.6.RELEASE'
}

repositories { 
    mavenCentral() 
    maven {
        url 'http://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots'
    }
}

sourceCompatibility = 1.8
targetCompatibility = 1.8

dependencies {
    compile 'io.dropwizard:dropwizard-core:' + dropwizardVersion
    compile 'io.dropwizard:dropwizard-jdbi:' + dropwizardVersion
    compile 'io.dropwizard:dropwizard-client:' + dropwizardVersion
    compile 'io.dropwizard:dropwizard-jackson:' + dropwizardVersion
    compile 'io.dropwizard:dropwizard-auth:' + dropwizardVersion
    compile 'io.dropwizard.metrics:metrics-core:' + dropwizardMetrics
    compile 'io.federecio:dropwizard-swagger:' + dropwizardSwaggerVersion
    compile 'commons-beanutils:commons-beanutils:' + apacheCommonsBeanUtilsVersion
    compile 'org.postgresql:postgresql:' + postgresVersion
    compile 'org.projectlombok:lombok:' + lombokVersion
    compile 'org.apache.oltu.oauth2:org.apache.oltu.oauth2.client:' + oauthVersion
    compile 'org.freemarker:freemarker:' + freemakerVersion
    compile 'org.antlr:antlr:3.2'
    compile 'be.tomcools:dropwizard-websocket-jee7-bundle:' + websocketBundle
    compile 'edu.stanford.nlp:stanford-corenlp:3.5.2'
    compile group: 'edu.stanford.nlp', name: 'stanford-corenlp', version: '3.5.2', classifier: 'models'
    compile 'io.swagger:swagger-parser:1.0.13'
    compile 'io.swagger:swagger-codegen:2.1.4'
    compile 'com.github.kagkarlsson:db-scheduler:1.4'
    compile 'org.rythmengine:rythm-engine:1.1.4-SNAPSHOT'
    compile 'org.glassfish.jersey.media:jersey-media-multipart:2.17'

    testCompile 'junit:junit:' + junitVersion
    testCompile 'io.dropwizard:dropwizard-testing:' + dropwizardVersion
    testCompile 'org.flywaydb:flyway-core:3.2.1'
    testCompile 'ru.yandex.qatools.embed:postgresql-embedded:' + postgresEmbedded

    // Required if generating equals, hashCode, or toString methods
    compile 'commons-lang:commons-lang:2.6'
    // Required if generating JSR-303 annotations
    compile 'javax.validation:validation-api:1.1.0.CR2'
    // Required if generating Jackson 2 annotations
    compile 'com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind:2.1.4'
    // Required if generating JodaTime data types
    compile 'joda-time:joda-time:2.2'
    //for json path
    compile 'com.jayway.jsonpath:json-path:2.0.0'
     compile 'com.h2database:h2:1.3.170'
    compile 'org.codehaus.groovy:groovy-all:2.4.5'  

}

mainClassName = "com.qlue.QlueApp"

shadowJar {
    mergeServiceFiles()
    exclude 'META-INF/*.DSA'
    exclude 'META-INF/*.RSA'
}

jar {
    manifest {  attributes 'Main-Class': mainClassName  }
}

test {
    reports {  
        junitXml.enabled = false
        html.enabled = true
    }
}
// running into bug https://github.com/flyway/flyway/issues/1001
flyway {
    url = 'jdbc:postgresql://demo3.folio3.com/qluedev'
    user = 'qlue'
    password = 'qlue'
}

if (System.getProperty("jsonschema2pojo")) {

jsonSchema2Pojo {
    source = file("${project.projectDir}/src/main/resources/assets").listFiles().findAll{it.name.endsWith(".json")}
    targetDirectory = file("${project.projectDir}/src/main/java")
    targetPackage = 'com.qlue.module.designtime.gen'
    includeJsr303Annotations = true
    propertyWordDelimiters = ['_'] as char[]
    sourceType = 'jsonschema'
    annotationStyle = 'jackson2'
}
}

run {  args 'server', dropwizardConfig  }
```

and my upload code is this

```html
@POST
                @Consumes(MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA)
                @ApiOperation(value = "Uploads the media(image) into the database and returns back id")
                @ApiResponses({ @ApiResponse(code = 422, message = "Validation error.") })
                public MediaDto receive(@FormDataParam("file") final InputStream inputStream, @FormDataParam("file") final FormDataContentDisposition contentDispositionHeader  ) {
                    return mediaService.receiveMultipart(inputStream, contentDispositionHeader);
                            }
```

What am I missing here.

Comment: Are you getting any errors/exceptions/bad status codes. Just saying the method isn't getting hit doesn't give us much to work with. Your dependency on `jersey-media-multipart` is fine

Comment: @peeskillet Getting 400 bad request upon invoking the resource.

Comment: How are you sending the request?

Comment: I am invoking it via postman client